# Use a thread in a QT Gui. It is destroyed

Tags: c++, multithreading, qtgui

I have a QT GUI . When I clic on a QPushButton, a calculation loop is called from another class which heritate from QThread. However, I have an error **QThread: destroyed while thread is still running**. I do not want to use pointers. I provide my minimal example below:

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "MainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    QObject::connect(this->ui.pushbutton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(process()));
}

void MainWindow::process()
{
    ListCalc m_Calcul(this);
    m_Calcul.start(); // This is the action I would like to put in a thread !
}
```

MainWindow.h

```
#include "ListCalc.h"

using namespace std;

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    Ui::MainWindowClass ui;

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ListCalc m_Calcul;

private slots:
    void process();
};
```

ListCalc.cpp

```
#include "ListCalc.h"

ListCalc::ListCalc(QMainWindow *parent)
{

}

ListCalc::~ListCalc()
{

}

void ListCalc::run()
{
    auto size = 30000;
    for (auto i = 0;i < size;++i)
    {
        std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

ListCalc.h

```
class ListCalc : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ListCalc(QMainWindow *parent);
    ~ListCalc();
    void run();    

};
```

Do you have any idea of what is the problem?

Comment: `ListCalc m_Calcul(this);` this introduces new local variable which is destroyed when function goes out of scope.

Comment: `ListCalc m_Calcul(this);` shadows the member variable of the same name and is local to the function. Use the member variable instead.

Comment: However, I declared this variable in my mainwindow.h ? It should not be local

Comment: rafix07 and Quentin are right, it is a local variable. It does not matter if it is in a .h or a .cpp file. What matters is that it is inside a function, so it is local to the function. To make it a member variable, you should put it inside the class definition. In your code, `Ui::MainWindowClass ui;` is for example a member variable.

Comment: As rafix07 and Quentin pointed out, your variable goes out of scope. Also check https://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/ for improving your Qt thread game.

Comment: Ok I understand, thank you. I will initialize ONLY in the class definition and setup in the function, using the setters of the class. However, if I want to reinitialize this variable, I cant. So, If I clic multiple times on my QPushButton, it will implement it instead of reconstructing it. Is there a way to reset this variable after job is done, in order to create a new one at the next passage in run() ?

Comment: Thank you, I succeeded with your help :)